# How do I intercept property loading on Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to intercept the property loading of certain properties in Spring Boot.

Example:

I store a value that is encrypted in my properties file, I would like to be able to decrypt it when I load it to my `@Configuration` annotated class.

Essentially I want to be able to intercept the processor that reads from properties files and populates the class.

I saw that this is possible with some workarounds using `ConversionService` but in this case I am talking about `String` to `String` so it doesn't apply.

Does Spring Boot provide such a feature?

Comment: Take a look into http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html

Comment: While I realize this is not exactly what you are looking for, you could also use Spring's @Value annotation along with a spel statement to modify the property value prior to binding in a bean. Obviously, this is not ideal if you need to use value in multiple places. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Answer (score -1):

Add an init method and annotate with an @PostConstruct, inside the method implement the code for decoding the encoded string value

Comment: You might want to add an example on how to do this and provide a link for further documentation / references if available :)